# Transaction scope c#

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I have two insert statements which are inserting records in a database. I have used transaction scope so that in case any of the statement fails, none of the records get updated. In the second procedurem the insert is failing but it's inserting record in the database for the first statement. What i am missing in the code?

Connection String

```
<add name="Transac.Properties.Settings.TransacDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Transac;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var scopeOptions = new TransactionOptions();
    scopeOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    scopeOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,scopeOptions)) {
        try {

                cmd = new SqlCommand("SalesSave", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BillNo", lblBillNo.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustName", cboCust_Name.Text.ToUpper()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mobile", txtMob.Text));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                cmd = new SqlCommand("SubSave", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SubBillNo", lblBillNo.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ItemName", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()));
                //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Price", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            transactionScope.Complete();
            transactionScope.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e1) {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Stored Proc 1:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SalesSave]
(  
    @SalesBillNo as varchar(50),
    @CustName as varchar(50),
    @Mobile as nvarchar(50)

)   
AS
    begin
        insert into Sales(

                         SalesBillno,
                         CustName,
                         Mobile

                         )

                values (

                         @SalesBillNo,
                         @CustName,
                         @Mobile

                         )
    end
```

Stored Proc 2

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SubSave]
@SubSalesBillNo as varchar(50),
@ItemName as nvarchar(50),
@Qty as money,
@Price as money

AS
    begin
         INSERT INTO SubSales 
         VALUES(
                @SubSalesBillNo,
                @ItemName,
                @Qty,
                @Price   
                )
    end
```

Comment: Is your messagebox showing an exception from the 2nd stored proc?
Why are you calling dispose when you have a Using block?

Comment: yes its showing exception in 2nd stored proc as i have commented a parameter explicitly so that it will throw error and transaction will roll back but its not. prior i was using transaction statement that's why dispose is there i will remove it

Comment: The real question is: What's the purpose of using 3 transactions at all? Also: What'S the purpose of using a transation on only one command?

Comment: What database are you using? Does it support these (potentially distributed) and nested transactions?

Comment: am using SQLExpress 2008 component. earlier i did try by using one one transaction scope as its not worked so i modify it and tried with three. my aim is only to rollback the transaction i just did some R&D but had a hard luck. i have configured DTC in my system

Comment: There's no point having three transactions. Remove the two `innerScope` transactions and all references to them and try again.

Comment: yes i have removed two innerscope and tried that also. still not working.

Comment: do i need to set xact_abort ON on both the table?

Comment: What you have here looks correct (although i would omit the transactionScope.Dispose() call because Using does that for you automatically). 
Perhaps you should post your connection string and both stored procs. 
You could also examine the Event Log.  Perhaps MSDTC is putting error or warning messages there that are relevant.

Comment: Connection string i am using in app.config    <add name="Transac.Properties.Settings.TransacDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Transac;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must open a database connection within the transaction scope and use that for this to work.

Comment: Man you saved my day.. just added a connection within the transaction scope and it works.. thanks a lot... :) but one question why is it so using a connection within the transaction scope?

Comment: It is during the `connection.Open()` call that the .NET framework looks for any active transaction scopes that the connection being opened should be enlisted in.